# How to implement Sunbird telemetry in React

Tags: reactjs, open-telemetry, telemetry

I want to implement the Sunbird telemetry in a React project

[https://telemetry.sunbird.org/use/jslibrary#starti]
I've gone through this website, but I have no idea where to start. Can anyone help me with how to start, how to implement it, and whether there are any GitHub repositories available?